# Linking combobox in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, combobox, binding, fxml

I have a interface with three combobox. Each combobox shows an attribute of an object and is sorted either alphabetical order or numerical order depending the case. When I select a item (atribute) from a combobox the other two shall select it's item (atribute) corresponding to the object.

I can't find documentation about it and don't have any clue about how to do it. I find information about nested combobox only but this is not the case.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Please post your code (see: [mre])

Answer (score 0):

In this example I've added a listener to one of the combo boxes, which "listens" for a change to the combo boxes selected value. Upon selecting a value within that combo box, the second combo box adjusts itself to have the corresponding value. You can take this same logic and apply it 3 ways by adding a listener to each combo box. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>();
combo.getItems().add("1");
combo.getItems().add("2");
combo.getItems().add("3");
combo.getSelectionModel().select(0); // value index to select

ComboBox<String> combo2 = new ComboBox<String>();
combo2.getItems().add("10");
combo2.getItems().add("20");
combo2.getItems().add("30");
combo2.getSelectionModel().select(0);

combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String oldVal, String newVal) {
        if (newVal.equals("1"))
            if (combo2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != 0)
                combo2.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        if (newVal.equals("2"))
            if (combo2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != 1)
            combo2.getSelectionModel().select(1);
        if (newVal.equals("3"))
            if (combo2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != 2)
            combo2.getSelectionModel().select(2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I understand the logic but, what if the combo2 instead of numbers it had words for example: "ten", "twenty", "thirty" in alphabetical order. Also what if it was hundreds of items.

Comment: You can easily make that happen with the information I've given above.

combo2.getSelectionmodel().select( combo.getSelectionModel.getSelectedIndex() )